Issues with same question but different answer? using PandasAi LLM:OpenAI
I have make some python code that able to analyze question and give out the answer. The problem is every time i tried the tools with the same question, the answer sometimes correct and sometimes wrong. How to deal with this? Im using PandasAi since im working on large data and use OpenAI as LLM to it.
openai.api_key = "API-Key"  # Replace with your OpenAI API key
llm = OpenAI(api_token=openai.api_key, temperature=0)  # Reduced randomness

def analyze_question(question, smart_df):
    """Analyze the given question using PandasAI and return the result."""
    try:
        question = preprocess_question(question)
        prompt = f"Analyze the dataset and answer: {question}"
        result = smart_df.chat(prompt)

        # Serialize the result safely to string
        if isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame):
            result_str = result.to_string(index=False)
        else:
            result_str = str(result)

        # Save data as JSON-compatible dictionary
        history.append({"question": question, "answer": result_str})
        save_history()
        return pd.DataFrame([[result_str]], columns=["Answer"])
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"Error analyzing question: {e}"
        history.append({"question": question, "answer": error_message})
        save_history()
        return pd.DataFrame([[error_message]], columns=["Error"])

def ask_question():
    """Handle the user's question and display the result."""
    question = question_entry.get()
    if question:
        global last_result
        last_result = analyze_question(question, smart_df)
        answer_text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        answer_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        if isinstance(last_result, pd.DataFrame):
            answer_text.insert(tk.END, last_result.to_string(index=False))
        else:
            answer_text.insert(tk.END, last_result)
        answer_text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Input Error", "Please enter a question.")


Don't you know that LLMs rely on randomness?

i know but is there any way to reduce it?

You already reduced temperature to minimum, the answer is already focused and deterministic. You could try to reduce the top_p from 1 to a value closer to 0. Don't change them both at the same time, you have to choose one of them and see the effect on the answers.
